# Strange lambda expression behaviour C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

There is a code:

```
    private Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            //TODO: this lambda-expression starts infinite loop
            return Plugins.Keys.First(x => x.FullName == args.Name);
           /* this code works fine
            foreach (Assembly xx in Plugins.Keys)
                if (xx.FullName == args.Name) return xx;
            return null;
            */
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

What's going on? Or may be it's me at the end of the working day? :)

**EDIT:**
There is no exception at the code. I ran debugger and after *return Plugins.Keys.First(x => x.FullName == args.Name);* method started again and again with args.Name = "System.Core.resources bla bla bla". 
When I've used foreach statement method returned successfully and there were not loop. It seems to be assembly resolving issue.

Comment: `return Plugins.Keys.Where(x => x.FullName == args.Name).First(); `

Comment: What's the exception you get?

Comment: how do you conclude it is an infinite loop?

Comment: Have you tried just logging what `args.Name` is at the top of this method? that will immediately tell you what is going on...

Comment: Looks like executing of lambda-expression starts recurring loop of resolving assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code that I can see, so the infinite loop must be caused by something else.

Other than that, it would be better to use just

```
// no need for try/catch
return Plugins.Keys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName == args.Name);
```